# How to use Arbre gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arbre

I want to try the Arbre gem for rails. There is an example on this page: https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre/blob/master/README.md

Where must I paste the next code?

```
html = Arbre::Context.new do
  h2 "Why is Arbre awesome?"

  ul do
    li "The DOM is implemented in ruby"
    li "You can create object oriented views"
    li "Templates suck"
  end
end
```

I want to try the code above, but I don't know where I must paste it. Which file? Which method? I pasted the code into my controller, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Make your question more complex please as It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I know you already accepted, but I found and included more info about using `arb` templates with Rails in my answer. Hope it helps! Looks like a cool project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you pasted, the `html` variable now holds the html for your page.

You can render it in the controller like this:

**app/controllers/whatever_controller.rb**

```
def show
  html = Arbre::Context.new do
    h2 "Why is Arbre awesome?"

    ul do
      li "The DOM is implemented in ruby"
      li "You can create object oriented views"
      li "Templates suck"
    end
  end
  render html: html.to_s
end
```

Also, it isn't well documented on the Github page, but digging through the source, it appears you can also use `abre` templates in place of regular erb views like so (notice the `.arb` file extension):

**app/views/whatever/show.html.arb**

```
h2 "Why is Arbre awesome?"

ul do
  li "The DOM is implemented in ruby"
  li "You can create object oriented views"
  li "Templates suck"
end
```

That way, your controller could look like this:

**app/controllers/whatever_controller.rb**

```
def show
  # nothing necessary here, by default renders show.html.arb
end
```

Comment: Yep, this convinced me to improve [the documentation](https://activeadmin.github.io/arbre/).